# Can't create simple dict from data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a table looks that:

```
          0                   1
0   2760023     XXXXXXXXYYYY111
1   2760024     XXXXXXXXYYYY112
2   2760042     XXXXXXXXYYYY113
3   2760011     XXXXXXXXYYYY114
4   2760041     XXXXXXXXYYYY115
5   2760012     XXXXXXXXYYYY116
6   2760033     XXXXXXXXYYYY117
```

No headers. I need to create simple dict:

```
dict = {2760023:XXXXXXXXYYYY111, 
        2760024:XXXXXXXXYYYY112... etc.}
```

I read a lot of post on SO and docs, but the result for me is wrong...
coz if I use a `to_dict()`(no matter what argument), as someone describe here:

> 26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary

I got a not simple dict but:

```
    {0: {0: 2760023,
  1: 2760024,
  2: 2760042,
  3: 2760011,
  4: 2760041,
  5: 2760012,
  6: 2760033},
 1: {0: 'XXXXXXXXYYYY111',
  1: 'XXXXXXXXYYYY112',
  2: 'XXXXXXXXYYYY113',
  3: 'XXXXXXXXYYYY114',
  4: 'XXXXXXXXYYYY115',
  5: 'XXXXXXXXYYYY116',
  6: 'XXXXXXXXYYYY117'}}
```

So it kinda lists in the list?
Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

P.S. table hase a data.frame type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just have 2 columns, you can also do:

```
dict(df.values)
```

---

```
{2760023: 'XXXXXXXXYYYY111',
 2760024: 'XXXXXXXXYYYY112',
 2760042: 'XXXXXXXXYYYY113',
 2760011: 'XXXXXXXXYYYY114',
 2760041: 'XXXXXXXXYYYY115',
 2760012: 'XXXXXXXXYYYY116',
 2760033: 'XXXXXXXXYYYY117'}
```

Comment: Wow, that's was so easy?! Thank u very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use any arguments for `to_dict`:

```
>>> df.set_index('0').to_dict()['1']
{2760023: 'XXXXXXXXYYYY111', 2760024: 'XXXXXXXXYYYY112', 2760042: 'XXXXXXXXYYYY113', 2760011: 'XXXXXXXXYYYY114', 2760041: 'XXXXXXXXYYYY115', 2760012: 'XXXXXXXXYYYY116', 2760033: 'XXXXXXXXYYYY117'}
>>>
```

Comment: I got a KeyError coz '0' when I folllow your answer. Then i try to do that this way:
`a = slow.set_index(slow.iloc[:,0]).to_dict()[slow.iloc[:,1]]` but now i have a error: 
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: @Artur Try: `a = slow.set_index(slow.iloc[:,0].item()).to_dict()[slow.iloc[:,1]]`

Answer (score 1):

There is other way also:

`{row[0]:row[1] for idx, row in df.iterrows()}`

With timeit, we have below for all solutions:

```
In [6]: %timeit {row[0]:row[1] for idx, row in df.iterrows()}                   
629 µs ± 56.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [7]: %timeit dict(df.values)                                                                                                                                                                      
44.1 µs ± 2.78 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [8]: %timeit df.set_index('0').to_dict()['1']                                                                                                                                                     
347 µs ± 18.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```